# c# reflection comparing 2 objects with boolean properties

Tags: c#, object, reflection

I have two objects with several properties that are of type boolean.
The properties are identical in terms of naming and I just want to make sure they are equal. I do a lot of these checks and want to know if anyone has any suggestion of a method that can do the following code in one step but is dynamic enough to check the property options by name if they have the same name?

```
 if (options != null && other != null)
            return options.Quantities == other.Quantities &&
                   options.SKUEntityKey == other.SKUEntityKey &&
                   options.LineItemType_Type == other.LineItemType_Type &&
                   options.SKUIdentifier == other.SKUIdentifier &&
                   options.Identifier == other.Identifier;
```

If what I'm asking isn't clear please let me know

Comment: if the two classes have identical naming, did you think about using an interface?

Comment: there's only one class defined the second comes from an API request. I noticed two answers using reflectors but that's expensive. The approach I have sorta resembles extending Equals but I'm looking for something alternative. I'll sleep on it..

Answer (score 0):

```
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ReflectOverProperties<TestClass, TestClass2>(new TestClass(), new TestClass2());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void ReflectOverProperties<T, Z>(T x, Z y)
        {
            var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
            foreach (var item in properties)
            {
                CompareProperty(x, y, item.Name);

            }
        }

        private static void CompareProperty<T, Z>(T x, Z y, string itemName)
        {
            dynamic originalValue = GetPropValue(x, itemName);
            dynamic newValue = GetPropValue(y, itemName);
            PropertyCompare(itemName, originalValue, newValue);

        }

        private static void PropertyCompare(string itemName, dynamic originalValue, dynamic newValue)
        {
            if (originalValue != newValue)
            {
             Console.Write($"Property {itemName} does not match");
            }
        }



        public static object GetPropValue(object src, string propName)
        {
            return src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null);
        }
    }

    public class TestClass
    {
        public TestClass()
        {
            Test1 = false;
            Test2 = false;
            Test3 = false;
        }
        public bool Test1 { get; set; }
        public bool Test2 { get; set; }
        public bool Test3 { get; set; }
    }
    public class TestClass2
    {
        public TestClass2()
        {
            Test1 = false;
            Test2 = false;
            Test3 = true;
        }
        public bool Test1 { get; set; }
        public bool Test2 { get; set; }
        public bool Test3 { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is some Code I modified pretty quick, which runs in console app. Hopefully set you in the right direction, was doing the same object now can be different. Just using some basic reflection and dynamic properties.

Comment: i appreciate the response ill check it out and keep you updated

Comment: Can you elaborate why you use `dynamic` instead of `object`? Later you could compare the objects using `.Equals` instead off `==`.

Comment: @thehennyy it was really just preference. you can use .Equals with dynamic also. Is really just something I wrote for testing nothing in prod

Answer (score 0):

I hope this terrible console app will at least give an idea of how to go about doing what you want:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person steve = new Person()
        {
            IsHungry = true,
            IsLazy = false,
            IsSleepy = true
        };

        Dog bella= new Dog()
        {
            IsHungry = true,
            IsLazy = false,
            IsSleepy = true
        };

        bool match = DoAllBoolPropertiesMatch(steve, bella);

        Console.WriteLine($"\r\n----> Do Bools in Objects Match?: {match}");
    }

    private static bool DoAllBoolPropertiesMatch(object obj1, object obj2)
    {
        // For each Boolean property of object 1, check object 2:
        foreach(PropertyInfo propInfo in obj1.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            // Property is boolean.
            if(propInfo.PropertyType == typeof(Boolean))
            {
                // Look for a property on obj2 with the same name that also returns a bool.
                PropertyInfo matchingPropInfo = obj2.GetType().GetProperty(propInfo.Name, typeof(Boolean));

                if(matchingPropInfo != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Evaluating Property {propInfo.Name} from obj1:");
                    Console.WriteLine($"  - Value for Obj1 = [{propInfo.GetValue(obj1)}]");
                    Console.WriteLine($"  - Value for Obj2 = [{matchingPropInfo.GetValue(obj2)}]");

                    if(Convert.ToBoolean(propInfo.GetValue(obj1)) != Convert.ToBoolean(matchingPropInfo.GetValue(obj2)))
                        return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public bool IsHungry { get; set; }
        public bool IsSleepy { get; set; }
        public bool IsLazy { get; set; }
    }

    public class Dog
    {
        public bool IsHungry { get; set; }
        public bool IsSleepy { get; set; }
        public bool IsLazy { get; set; }
    }
```